# list of dict with same key name

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to achieve the following output:
**`[{'Key': 'Language', 'Value': 'Python'}, {'Key': 'Version', 'Value': '3.7'}]`**

I have implemented a method to achieve the above output:

```
@cli.command('test', context_settings=dict(
    ignore_unknown_options=True,
    allow_extra_args=True
))
@click.pass_context
def test(ctx):
    data = dict()
    tags=dict()
    tag_list = list()
    for item in ctx.args:
        data.update([item.split('=')])
    for items in data.items():
        tags['Key'] = items[0]
        tags['Value'] = items[1]
        tag_list.append(tags)

    print(tag_list)
```

Method Call:
**python test.py test Language=Python Version=3.7**

But I am getting below output:
**`[{'Key': 'Version', 'Value': '3.7'}, {'Key': 'Version', 'Value': '3.7'}]`**

The is old dict is been replaced and then appended.

Can you please help me with this?

Thanks & Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mutating the same dict in the last loop, so your list will have references to the same dict.

Move this:

```
tags=dict()
```

...inside the final `for` loop:

```
for items in data.items():
    tags=dict()
```